# slapd -- push changes from consumer

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, chain

I got Producer and Consumer servers working using delta technique via TLS. 
Set up updateRef on consumer pointing to producer - so changes should be directed to the producer.
Got one problem though - when I try to make any change to the consumer it says "modifications require authentication", and I don't know how to fix it really.

I stumbled upon mention of slapo-chain overlay, but 
1. I can't find it in the lib folder on Ubuntu server, and
2. How to set it up using cn=config?

All help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solved that with slapo-chain.

Here's my (example) chain on consumer using startTLS:

```
dn: olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcChainConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {0}chain
olcChainCacheURI: FALSE
olcChainMaxReferralDepth: 1
olcChainReturnError: TRUE

dn: olcDatabase={0}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {0}ldap
olcDbStartTLS: none  starttls=no
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE

dn: olcDatabase={1}ldap,olcOverlay={0}chain,olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcLDAPConfig
objectClass: olcChainDatabase
olcDatabase: {1}ldap
olcDbURI: "ldap://example.com"
olcDbStartTLS: start  starttls=no
olcDbIDAssertBind: mode=self flags=prescriptive,proxy-authz-non-critical bindmethod=simple timeout=0 network-timeout=0 binddn="cn=syncer,ou=syncproviders,dc=example,dc=com" credentials="superpassword" keepalive=0:0:0
olcDbRebindAsUser: FALSE
olcDbChaseReferrals: TRUE
olcDbTFSupport: no
olcDbProxyWhoAmI: FALSE
olcDbProtocolVersion: 3
olcDbSingleConn: FALSE
olcDbCancel: abandon
olcDbUseTemporaryConn: FALSE
olcDbConnectionPoolMax: 16
olcDbNoRefs: FALSE
olcDbNoUndefFilter: FALSE
```

Be advised, i ran into some problems with authzPolicy on the producer's side, but that's another question ;)